# Finding correct CRS using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a GeoTIFF layer (downloaded from US Dept of Interior) that is US population density. The metadata claims it is in EPSG:4267, which isn't even intended for use in that part of the world. (east end is at -52°, I think). 
If I add this layer to a map containing the world boundaries (layer source - Natural Earth, CRS = 4326), the two layers look like this (Natural earth admin boundaries on the bottom):
[image]

How do I go about figuring out the the CRS for the population density layer?

Comment: EPSG:4267 is NAD27, so it could be a possibility for the US. However, based on the shape of the country in the image, it looks like a conic projection, perhaps Lambert Conformal or Albers Equal-Area. But even then, there may be another issue with units or scale because it seems way off

Comment: Looking at more of the metadata, it's pretty clear that something is seriously screwed up with this data - 
Extent
-683.9732411595443864,49.1100237560417554 : 641.3830255071220563,898.6748237560416328   
I guess it's not an issue of projection so much as finding the right values for description of the raster.

Comment: Since it does not seem to correspond to any known units or values, unless you eventually find out what they are, as a last resort, you could always try to georeference the image back to its correct location. I believe one of the conic projections should fit reasonably well with the raster.

Comment: Any information in the metadata beside 4267? If you include a link to the data, maybe someone can find some information.